# Why does a plain match expression compile, while a map_err call doesn't?

Tags: rust

Using rustc 1.30.1 and reqwest 0.9.5.

I have a function that calls several other functions, which may return different types of errors, in particular `std::io::Error` and `reqwest::Error`.

To propagate these to the caller, the simplest solution seems to be to put them in a `Box`, which conveniently implements the `From<Error>` trait as well as the `Error` trait itself. Like this:

```
fn fetch_input() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    ...
    let session_cookie = load_session_cookie()?; // Returns Result<String, io::Error>
    let text: Result<String, reqwest::Error> = ...;
    text.map_err(Box::new) // Compile error on this line
}
```

However, that code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types                                                               
  --> src/main.rs:26:5                                                                       
   |                                                                                         
16 | fn fetch_input() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {                 
   |                     ------------------------------ expected `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>` because of return type
...                                                                                          
26 |     text.map_err(Box::new)                                                              
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait std::error::Error, found struct `reqwest::Error`
   |                                                                                         
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<_, std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, std::boxed::Box<reqwest::Error>>`
```

If I replace the `map_err` call by a plain old `match` expression, all is fine:

```
    match text {
        Ok(t) => Ok(t),
        Err(e) => Err(Box::new(e)),
    }
```

Note that this is identical to the body of the `map_err` implementation in the standard library. So why doesn't my `map_err` call pass the type checker? Needless to say, [`reqwest::Error` does implement the `std::error::Error` trait](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.9.5/reqwest/struct.Error.html#impl-Error).

I also wonder where the `'static` lifetime in the error message is coming from. If it turns out to be unrelated, I might open a different question for it.

Comment: See [RFC 599](https://github.com/nox/rust-rfcs/blob/master/text/0599-default-object-bound.md) for your side question.

Comment: `text.map_err(From::from)` or `text.map_err(|e| From::from(Box::new(e)))` don't ask I never fully understood. https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Box::new` does one thing, and one thing only: takes a `reqwest::Error` and puts it inside a `Box<reqwest::Error>`.

The *expression* `Box::new(e)` is doing *two* things: calls `Box::new` which takes a `reqwest::Error` and puts it inside a `Box<reqwest::Error>`, **and then** it coerces the `Box<reqwest::Error>` into a `Box<dyn Error>`.

Coercing types is something Rust generally tries to avoid.  `Box<T>` → `Box<dyn Trait>` (and other similar, direct pointer→pointer coercions) is an exception.  In particular, Rust *will not* coerce `Result<T, Box<Err>>` to `Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>`.

As for your aside: because `dyn Trait` always requires an associated lifetime.  When you put `dyn Trait` inside a box, it is implicitly assumed to be `'static`.  When you have `&'a dyn Trait`, it's assumed to be `'a`.

Comment: Rust _does_ coerce `Result<T, Box<Err>>` to `Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>`. Just try it; it's a standard unsized coercion. The reason for the error is more subtle – it's basically a shortcoming of the type inference algorithm.

Comment: Here is a playground link demonstrating the coercion: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e05e9eb050992c85d3e25357cfa6ad60

Comment: @SvenMarnach No, it doesn't.  That code does not demonstrate what you think it demonstrates.  You've made exactly the same mistake as the OP: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=596a741dba6562cdf942f19bef978233

Comment: You are right – the coercion in my code is only for the box, and `Result` does not implement `CoerceUnsized`.

Comment: @Thomas: `CoerceUnsized`.  `Box<T>` → `Box<dyn Trait>` is more akin (though still not the same) as `SomeObject` → `Interface`.  You can't do `Vec<T>` → `Vec<dyn Trait>` because that doesn't make sense.  `Box<T>` → `Box<dyn Trait>` does, so you can.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I was wondering when exactly Rust will and won't do such coercions, and found https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html which has the full details. The answer to my original question follows from the fact that passing `Box::new` as a function does not create a coercion site.

Comment: @Thomas This page actually doesn't have all the details, unfortunately. There is a [slightly more complete version in the language reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html), but it's still lacking special cases. For example it does not mention that enum variant constructors in a coercion site propagate the coercion to their arguments, which is why I thought my example linked above demonstrates that unsized coercions for `Result` are performed. There are also subtleties to how the return type of the closure you pass to `map_err()` is inferred.